# I have a runtime error when combine Umbraco + Ucommerce .Net

Tags: .net, azure, umbraco, umbraco-ucommerce

I'm trying to debug a webshop system that is running on Umbraco with Ucommerce on top, the system is hosted in Azure Web. The webshop is randomly not responding (each 12-24 h). I looked in the errorlog and found this, however I'm not sure how to solve this problem? Does anyone have a clue or hint?

```
<Provider Name=".NET Runtime"/><EventID>1022</EventID><Level>1</Level><Task>0</Task><Keywords>Keywords</Keywords><TimeCreated SystemTime="2018-04-15T01:34:32Z"/><EventRecordID>866832968</EventRecordID><Channel>Application</Channel><Computer>RD000B3AB1244C</Computer><Security/></System><EventData><Data>.NET Runtime version 4.0.30319.0 - Loading profiler failed.  Failed trying to receive from out of process a request to attach a profiler.  HRESULT: 0x8007006d.  Process ID (decimal): 3576.  Message ID: [0x250d].</Data></EventData></Event><Event><System><Provider Name=".NET Runtime"/>
```

Comment: Take a look at the Umbraco Log as well in ~/App_Data/Logs - it should provide the full exception with any luck

Comment: thanks for the input. I looked in the logs, however when the webshop crashed the first line in the logfile was
2018-04-15 06:34:48,141 [13] INFO  Umbraco.Core.CoreBootManager - Umbraco 7.3.4 application starting on RD00CCCB1244C

I looks like it dont log why it crashed, but just that it's starting.

Comment: However I just saw, that each time I changed the web.config file in the following hours. It made the same (.net runtime error) each time it was starting, can this error be due to a bad configuration? ex. an Connection string to the database etc.

Comment: We had a similar issue on Azure with Umbraco 7.3. It would go offline and be very difficult to get back to life. We upgraded to Umbraco 7.5 and the issue was resolved. We weren't able to find any clues in the logs, but it seemed related to the compilation process of the Razer views - again totally unverified